# Cannot test payment reversal webhook event in sandbox. PayPal REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-webhooks

I need to test payment reversal (not refund)  webhook events. I tried using the webhook simulator but am unable to search using the refund id given by it.  Is there any other way I can force a sandbox payment into throwing a reversal event?

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks Simulator generates a sample payload for an event and does not create an actual transaction. You won't be able to search refund Id generated by webhooks simulator.

You can read more about Payment Reversal at http://www.ebay.com/gds/Why-has-my-paypal-payment-been-reversed-/10000000000112025/g.html

This is a behavior which PayPal needs to trigger, and can not be triggered by a PayPal user.

Comment: That's disappointing.  Not sure what the point of the sandbox is then if we cannot feel confident that our code will work as it should live. Especially regarding something as serious as a payment reversal, which happens to vary from the normal payment flow.

Comment: Hi Billy, I understand your point. You ae right Sandbox is used for testing functionality before going live, infact PayPal Sandbox provides that feature too. But you are using simulator for that purposes which is a mock and does not involve actual transactions. Also for Payment Reversal, this is not a user flow, but PayPal is involved in this. If you want i can help you with a payment reversal, but please note that, it is again PayPal involvement for that and not something you can trigger as a user on live/Sandbox.